# trying to figure out how to save data after ending program

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to save data after ending a program and came across this piece of code online :

```
#input variable
input_dictionary = {"one" : 1, "two" : 2}
 
file = open("Python.txt", "w")
file.write("%s = %s\n" %("input_dictionary", input_dictionary))
 
file.close()
 
f = open('Python.txt', 'r')
if f.mode=='r':
    contents= f.read()
```

The code works very well but I'm having trouble understanding some parts and do not want to  copy or use code I do not understand.  Can someone please explain to me how this code works, specifically in these parts :

- line 4 there is 'w' what does that mean?
- line 5 there is some gibbrish "%s = %s\n" %("input_dictionary" what does that mean?
- line 9 there is 'r' similar to the w, what does that mean?
- line 10 I dont understand at all
- line 11 what is f?

please help and thanks for taking the time to read this over :)

Comment: This might help: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Please look at [Reading and Writing files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files): `'w'` indicates that the file is opened in write mode, `'r'` indicates the file is opened in read-only mode; [Fancier Output Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting): `%s` is a format specifier and uses the old string formatting syntax; and Python syntax for assignment: `f` is the file object.

Answer (score 1):

1. In `Line 4` `w` means `write mode`. In other words you have
   opened the file in `write mode` so you can write into the file.
   There are other modes too in which the file can be opened are : `r for read` , `r+ for both read and write` etc.
2. In `line 5` the quote `"%s = %s\n" %("input_dictionary"` is nothing but formating scheme. `%s = %s/n` means that you want to replace it with the `input_dictionary`.
3. In `line 9` as mentioned above `r` means that you want to open the file in `read mode`.
4. In `line 10` it is saying that if `f (the file)` if open in `read mode` then read the file. This line is actually optional and you can remove for your simplicity.
5. In `line 11` as mentioned in `line 9` : `f = open('Python.txt', 'r')`, so here `f` is nothing but the `file - Python.txt`

Answer (score 0):

> line 4 there is 'w' what does that mean?

"w" means write to open the file in write mode. [The documentation for the `open()`] function explains this. Learning how to find and read docs is an important skill.

> line 5 there is some gibbrish "%s = %s\n" %("input_dictionary" what does that mean?

This "gibberish" is called [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting). This uses the old-style syntax. We now use what are called "f-strings" for this kind of thing instead.

> line 9 there is 'r' similar to the w, what does that mean?

"r" means read.

> line 10 I dont understand at all

This is an `if` statement to compare two values. I think this is intended to check that the file was opened in read mode. But this is unnecessary because line 9 explicitly uses the `"r"` flag.

> line 11 what is f?

`f` is a variable that was created on line 9

Comment: does this string formatting need to be % or can it be a different type of formatting?

Comment: @mike The `"%s"` is part of the [string formatting language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec). The `"some stuff" % (some other stuff)` syntax is the old Python 2 syntax for formatting. In new code, I suggest using f-strings instead.

Comment: @mike I suggest you work through a python tutorial to understand the basics. The official one posted in the first comment below your question is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple explanation,

> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html is relevant to most of your problems

line 4:
Here the `open` file takes two arguments the first one is the file path and the second one is the mode, which is represented by a string. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

> mode is an optional string that specifies the mode in which the file is opened. It defaults to 'r' which means open for reading in text mode. Other common values are 'w' for writing (truncating the file if it already exists), 'x' for exclusive creation, and 'a' for appending (which on some Unix systems, means that all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position)

line 5:
Here in the fifth line `%s` is used for formatting a string. for example `"your name is %s" % "tom"` would return a string `your name is tom`. A more simpler way of doing this is using fstring. So the same string would look like. [old string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#old-string-formatting),  [fstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

```
file.write(f"input_dictionary = {input_dectionary}\n")
```

line 9: look at the answer for line 4

line 10: Here it uses the `if` statement to check if the variable `f.mode` is equal to `"r"`. The variable `f.mode` in this situation is always going to be `"r"` so this line is unnecessary.

line 11: Here the `f` (variable) is a the output of `open('Python.txt', 'r')` created in line 9.